# How high could a Lego tower be?

Tags: science-based, construction

I just won the national lottery! I am a billionaire, and can do whatever I want with my money!

Tv interviewer asks me what would I do with this money. Then, come the Idea.

I remember this guy when I was young, Kevin, if I remember correctly. His parents were rich, way richer than mine. And therefore, he had much more Lego than me. As he was my direct neighbour, he used to play in the garden, or to expose his big towers on her balcony, so I could see that he had more Legos than me.

I still remember him, and want my revenge.

Here is my plan. Kevin lives in a rural area, and there are only fields across the roads. I buy them all. Now, I want to build the highest Lego tower possible, just in front of his house. Money isn't a problem anymore, the sky is the limit.

- I would be ok if the foundation are not in Lego, but otherwise, all the towers must be simple Lego bricks.
- width/length shouldn't be a problem, as I have a big land

### How high could my Lego tower be?

PS: This have been asked/answer elsewhere, but I'm not ok with the answers. For example:

- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-high-can-a-Lego-brick-tower-be): Just tell us a random number, without showing us the calculations. Bonus point for wondering if we have enough pieces.
- [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20578627): Base theorical heigh according to pressure/weight until a brick collapse, before telling us it would be impossible

Other articles are similar, based on the weight, but don't include the need of foundations, wind resistance...

Comment: *This have been asked/answer elsewhere, but I'm not ok with the answers* You will have to explain why not, and what makes your question different. The pressure/weight calculation is a pretty definitive one and works for any material: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel#Height), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/57g0md/what_is_the_highest_a_mountain_can_be_is_there_a/), [3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321141279_How_tall_can_gelatin_towers_be_An_introduction_to_elasticity_and_buckling)

Comment: Your condition about the foundation not having to be lego is irrelevant. The lego part on top of it will have a maximum height. The foundation will itself also have a maximum height (less than its own maximum height based on its material, because the lego part is on top of it).

Comment: @JanDoggen Not an architect, so I may be wrong, but is pressure/weight really the only factor? aren't there diference between theory and real world, were for example a not-perfectlysymetric tower would collapse if it's 2k3 tall? and about the lego/foundation, i mesure thei heigh of the tower once it's lego, not from the foundation

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be infinitely tall. It all depends on how thick it is. It might be wider than tall, but if you have enough pieces im pretty sure there is no limit to the height. Except maybe by gravity and it collapsing into a blackhole if you build it in space.

Comment: The BBC article seems a perfectly good one.  But note the detailed design/structure of the tower is significant.  E.g. the Eiffel Tower is an iron structure, but the structural design is what makes height possible - a more naive design would not be as good.

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstanding you. You want to **include** other external factors (in the assumption that the maximum height will be lower than the one dictated by height alone). But that is not answerable: all you give as about external factors is that it's a rural area. Or is it still different, e.g. you want to have an answer about how the Lego bricks should be 'engineered' together, i.e. what bricks in what relation? How about editing your question so that it is clearer?

Comment: Being a billionaire is not enough. A 2x2 Lego brick costs 13p (in the UK) and is 16mm x 16mm x 12mm, so 3cc. Let’s say you can get them for 3p in bulk, so £1 will buy you 33. You can buy 33 billion bricks for £1 billion, with a volume of 100 billion cc. That’s 100,000 cubic metres, so the biggest cubical tower you could build would be only 46.4 meters high. You would need to be a trillionaire to build a really big tower, and even then, if it was a cube it would be only 464 meters high.

Comment: @Kepotx  What do you want revenge for?  Do you want revenge on Kevin for choosing to be born to wealthier parents and thus having more legos than you when you were young?  Or do you want to get revenge of Kevin for  deliberately playing with his legos where you could see them in order to make you feel bad?  And if so, how do you know that was Kevin's motive for playing with his legos in those places?  Are you just assuming that was Kevin's motive?   Are you sure Kevin even remembers you or won't just think how lucky he is that some nut decided to beautify the area with a giant lego tower?

Comment: @Mike Scott  Maybe he plans to build, not a cubical Lego tower, but a tall Lego tower with a square cross section like 432 Park avenue NYC, or a tall pyramidal Lego tower.  I think that he could probably build a highly impressive 100 meter Lego tower.

Comment: lego already has a tower height record people constantly compeat for. the current record is 35 meters, http://www.recordholders.org/en/list/lego.html

Comment: We’ll need more restrictions on tower height/width requirements before I show up on your property and dump a literal landslide of legos without even bothering to connect them. Given a non-negligible angle of repose, the pile will have height, and with infinite space and legos the pile can probably be indefinitely high.

Comment: For people saying that height can be unlimited, there is a limit to how tall a mountain can be. I'm pretty sure for Lego blocks this limit would be less than for typical rock like granite.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper no matter how wide the tower, in the end the weight will crush the pieces at the bottom. Of course you could keep building on top of the crushed pieces, but then you hit another limit when the gravitational attraction makes the structure collapse in itself (there is a reason for the core of the Earth not having empty spaces). The definitive limit is when the tower is so masive that the inner pieces start to suffer nuclear reactions (in its way to become a star) or the whole structure collapses in a black hole... OH MY GOD WE ARE ALL GONNA DAY BECAUSE THE OP!!!!!

Comment: @SJuan76, the question doesn't say that the bricks cant be crushed, or lego dust. A crushed lego brick is a still a lego brick by some definitions. Infinity might be an exaggeration, but in space you can probably make a lego tower hundreds of thousands of miles long before it has any noticeable gravity.

Answer (score 14):

### 10.8km high.

I wrote up a little program (code below) to find the exact break point at which we reach the 4240 Newton limit that was provided as enough to crush a lego block by your BBC article. I picked a pyramid, an extremely stable structure, and one that has a very wide base to properly distribute the weight above it, allowing it to get much taller than a tower. I hope you really do have plenty of land! I am running off of the following assumptions, that or course aren't necessarily true:

1. Your legos are being built on a perfectly flat surface.
2. The legos distribute their weight perfectly

### Results

1125001 lego blocks high. 1125001 * 9.6mm ~= 10.8km 
You could get this result for a while, bot note that your tower will slowly sink down over time, plastic deformation is bound to happen! You now have the pleasure of owning the biggest lego tower ever, but also the tallest man-made structure ever! Now just to watch it slowly melt...

### Code

```
i = 1
weight = 0
totalLegos = 0
while True:
    # Size of new bottom layer
    base = i**2
    totalLegos += base
    # Add size of previously added layer to
    # total weight load on the base layer
    weight += ((i-1)**2) * .001152 # Weight of lego is 1.152g -> kg
    # Too heavy?
    if weight/base >= 432:
        print("Maximum reached!")
        print("{}/{} = {} >= 432".format(weight, base, weight/base))
        print("    Levels: {}".format(i))
        print("    Total weight: {}".format(weight+base*.001152))
        print("    Total legos:  {}".format(totalLegos))
        break
    else:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

### Output

```
546752187002808.0/1265629500004 = 432.00019200017067 >= 432
    Levels: 1125002
    Total weight: 546753645007992.0
    Total legos:  474612539069437505
```

Sources:
[BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20578627)
[Exact lego dimensions](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/288/what-are-the-dimensions-of-a-lego-brick)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE *Skyler*! Cool answer. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: The thing is that legos won't perfectly distribute their weight, the on on the middle of the base will bear much more weight than those in the corners so it won't work, the one in the middle will be crushed and the neighbouring one will have to bear what it bore and get crushed too etc

Comment: @Jean-Abdel please read the assumptions made, the true distribution in weight for the legos is an unknown.

Comment: Note that this is (by my quick calculation) about 66 times more plastic than exists in the entire world right now.

Comment: That's roughly half a trillion tonnes with of Lego. The Burj Khalifa is only like 800,000 tonnes (very rough estimate), so that's like 600,000x free massive have the largest tower ever constructed. Admittedly with a pyramid like this the weight will be spread out (much) more, but I don't think you'll have a problem with *slow* sinking, I expect the ground would immediately subside under the structure

Comment: @realityChemist very true, But by my rough calculation ((167m)^2/(11250m)^2), its base is over 4500 times as large... So only 133x the amount of pressure on the ground... heh heh... hope he built it on a mile deep concrete foundation...

Comment: You’d need about $10 quadrillion to buy that much Lego. It’s going to take more than a lottery win.

Comment: @MikeScott Well, sure, if you paid retail price. It would be much, much cheaper to buy the company, along with all of the plastic manufacturing facilities on earth.

Comment: One word : Wind.  Long before this tower reached 1 km it would start experiencing wind forces way beyond the ability of Lego bricks to maintain a bond in.  The tower would experience the same effects that all tall structures do.

Comment: @Skyler so you're assumption is wrong